# 1Hz clock for a D FlipFlop VHDL

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, vhdl

I am trying to implement a 1hz clock for a D flipflop in VHDL.

Below is my code:

```
entity d_flip_flop is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC);
end d_flip_flop;

architecture Behavioral of d_flip_flop is
signal clk_div: std_logic; --divided clock
begin

--process to divide clock
clk_divider: process(clk) --clk is the clock port
variable clk_count: std_logic_vector(25 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if clk'event and clk = '1' then
        clk_count <= clk_count+1;
        clk_div <= clk_count(25);
    end if;
end process;

--main process  
main:process(clk_div)
    begin
        if clk'event and clk = '1' then
            Q <= D;
        end if;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

But when I tried to compile it, the following error is reported:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "F:/EE4218/XQ/d_flip_flop.vhd" Line 47. + can
>   not have such operands in this context.

I have checked with several reference for the syntax and found nothing wrong with it. Can anyone point out the cause of the error ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem adding std\_logic\_vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042832/problem-adding-std-logic-vectors)

Comment: This was the fourth hit on Google searching for the exact error message (#1 and #3 referred to std_logic).

Answer (score 1):

clk_count is being used to represent a number, not a bag of bits.

So use the type system instead of fighting it, and declare it as a number or at least some numeric type.

The best tool for this purpose, since you need to extract a bit from it, is numeric_std.unsigned.

So add `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`after the `library ieee;` clause, declare it as

```
variable clk_count: unsigned(25 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Brian has the best answer, for powers-of-two anyway.  Arguably, for other wrap around values, you should also use an `integer` for `clock_count` and wrap it:

```
signal clk_div : std_logic := '0';

clk_divider: process(clk) --clk is the clock port
subtype t_clk_count: integer range 0 to 12345678; -- for example
variable clk_count: t_clk_count := 0;
begin
    if clk'event and clk = '1' then
        if clk_count+1 >= t_clk_count'high then
           clk_div <= not clk_div;
           clk_count <= 0;
        else
            clk_count <= clk_count+1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: My preference is also for integer (so I said "declare it as a number or ...") , even though you then have to code the wrap-round behaviour explicitly. But for this application where power-of-2 overflow is wanted, I went for the simpler answer.  +1 for going the extra mile.

Answer (score -1):

In process **clk_divider** modify the following line:

```
clk_count <= clk_count +1;
```

to

```
clk_count := std_logic_vector(UNSIGNED(clk_count) + 1);
```

This is because **clk_count** is defined as a *variable* of type 'std_logic_vector'.

Comment: He will also need to add "use ieee.numeric_std.all" after "library ieee";

Comment: That's a quick hack (or Verilog users') fix IMHO