# 4-bit ALU using VHDL showing error: no function declarations for operator "+" ("-", "*",and "/")

Tags: vhdl, alu, ghdl

When I compile this code using ghdl it produces errors.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity alu is

 generic ( constant N: natural := 1 );     

       port( a,b : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
             sel : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
             y : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
             x: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
             cout : out std_logic);
end alu;


architecture behavioral of alu is
signal rslt : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal tmp :  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin


process(a,b,sel)


begin

case sel is

        when "0000"=>

         rslt<= a + b;        -- Line 33
         when "0001"=>
         rslt<= a - b;        -- Line 35
          when "0010"=>
          x<= (unsigned(a)) * (unsigned(b)); -- Line 37
          when "0011"=>
          x<=(unsigned(a)) / (unsigned(b));   -- Line 39
          when "0100"=>
         rslt<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) sll N);
          when "0101"=>
         rslt<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) srl N);
         when "0110"=>
         rslt<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) rol N);
          when "0111"=>
         rslt<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) ror N);
          when "1000"=>
         rslt<= a and b;
          when "1001"=>
         rslt<= a or b;
           when "1010"=>
         rslt<= a xor b;
           when "1011"=>
         rslt<= a xnor b;
           when "1100"=>
         rslt<= a nand b;
           when "1101"=>
         rslt<= a nor b;
            when "1110"=>
               if (a > b) then
                     rslt<= "0001";
                else
                    rslt<="0000";
                end if;
          when "1111"=>
               if (a = b)then
                    rslt<="0001";
               else
                    rslt<="0000";
               end if;
          when others=> 
                 rslt<= "0000";
       end case;
   end process;

y<=rslt;
tmp<= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b);     -- Line 78
cout<=tmp(4);
end behavioral;
```

> ghdl -a alu.vhdl
>   alu.vhdl:33:19:error: no function declarations for operator "+"
>   alu.vhdl:35:19:error: no function declarations for operator "-"
>   alu.vhdl:37:29:error: no function declarations for operator "*"
>   alu.vhdl:39:28:error: no function declarations for operator "/"
>   alu.vhdl:78:17:error: no function declarations for operator "+"

When using unsigned arithmetic, How can I make these operators available?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend better formatting your errors and further explaining what are you trying to achieve. Regardless, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042832/error-adding-std-logic-vectors) as it seems that you are having problems to understand how VHDL supports vector operations.

Comment: The -2008 revision package numeric_std_unsigned provides arithmetic operations on std_logic_vector values (treated as unsigned, a super set of the functionality provided by delirium's linked Synopsys std_logic_unsigned and std_logic_arith, neither part of the standard). There's also type conversions for the operands of the operators in question as well as type conversion of the return value assigned to a std_logic_vector. You could use ports and intermediary signals that are type unsigned representing binary numbers without changing or adding use clauses and removing the type conversions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no function declarations for operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861761/no-function-declarations-for-operator)

Comment: It seems you copied code without knowing what it does. I say that because your code contains the answers to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stackoverflow. You are apparently not very familiar with typed languages. VHDL is a typed language in which variables, signals, constants have a type, like `bit`, `integer`, `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)` or `unsigned(3 downto 0)`. And these types define what can be done and what cannot.

1. By default you cannot add two `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)` and get a result that is also a `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)`. This is what you try to do with `rslt<= a + b;`. The compiler simply tells you that no such `"+"` operator is visible.
2. Same for `rslt<= a - b;`  with the `"-"` operator.
3. `x<= (unsigned(a)) * (unsigned(b));` is slightly better because you did not try to multiply two `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)`. You converted them to `unsigned(3 downto 0)` instead. Good choice because the `ieee.numeric_std` package overloads the `"*"` operator for the `unsigned(...)` types. Unfortunately you try to assign the result to a `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` while the `ieee.numeric_std."*"` operator returns a `unsigned(7 downto 0)`. So, here again, the compiler complains that it does not find a suitable `"*"` operator. Note: the parentheses are not needed. You could simply write `unsigned(a) * unsigned(b)`.
4. The other errors are left unexplained as an exercise.

I suggest that you read again your VHDL book and understand what types are, what kind of operations are defined by default on `std_logic_vector(...)` and `unsigned(...)` types and what extra operations are defined on the same types by the two packages you declare (`ieee.std_logic_1164` and `ieee.numeric_std`).